# Setting different constrains per truck in ORTools

Tags: python, routes, or-tools, restrict, here-maps-rest

We are in development of route optimization software which uses HERE Maps and we need to make the following:

- Some trucks can pass through all countries (they have all the licences required to pass through)
- Some need to go around specific countries, meaning, to find secondary, maybe tertiary path to reach the  destination

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to specify which truck has what permission, so they can be passed to the solver 
   combined?
2. If not, what is the optimal way to achieve this result? Any other way around?

So far, we have tried restricting a country by blacklisting it in the HERE Maps API key, but that won't be taken in consideration by the solver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In OR-Tools you can provide a transit callback index per vehicles so if a bunch of vehicles can't reach few locations simply return MAX_INT64 in the callback associated to these vehicles...

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand the question, I don't know if the problem is VRP or routing.

- If the problem is VRP, the indication of Mizux is the correct one,
  you just have to return in the callback the valid vehicle list for that pickup and delivery.
- If the problem is about routing, that is from where you are passing through, you can solve it in Nokia Here with the routing restrictions.